# How to preserve query string on reload

Tags: angular

So,
I route to a page  "*localhost:4200/lists?title=angular,node&locations=delhi,noida*", it works fine.
Now when I reload , the query string gets lost with remaining URL "*localhost:4200*"

I noticed that I got an error in the LISTSCOMPONENT (localhost:4200/lists) because there was no query.

I searched a lot and unable to find a definite answer or a industry way.

I though of preserving the query string in localStorage but right away on reload but

- the string is getting lost then getting that from localStorage
- and then somehow reloading the route with the saved string that is already reloaded doesn't seem to be the best way.

### Routes in app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modules/home/home.module')
        .then(m => m.HomeModule)
    }
];
```

### Routes in home module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {  
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, 
    children: [
      {  path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
      { path: 'job-listing', component: JobListingComponent }
    ] 
  }
]
```

### Navigation to JobList component

It is from a filter component that is inside HomePageComponent

```
this.router.navigate(['/job-listing'], {
   queryParams: queryOb
} );
```

Comment: Something is routing you back to `localhost:4200` after reloading, when after it reloads you should still be on `localhost:4200/lists`

Comment: Please share your relevant code for routing.

Comment: I've included the code. Please let me know if I can do anything else to elaborate more.
@MikeS. yea I was wondering about that and even I got an error in the list component means that got rendered. I dont know why is that.

Comment: I also want to add one more thing, if I reload  `localhost:4200/job-listing` without query parameters , it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

After setting query params with `router.navigate`, I was accessing an array from the query params with `router.snapshot.queryParams`lets say, `{skills: ['Angular 2', 'JavaScript]}`.

But on reload, result was `{ skills: 'Angular 2,JavaScript}` and that caused the error and re-routing to root.